# Cluster algorithm which minimizes a distance while fulfilling a constraint

Tags: optimization, clustering

I have data of 90 persons.

Data of a person:
- x coordinate
- y coordinate
- score (1 to 6)

I want to form groups of 9 people each so that:
- the distance between people in one group is as small as possible
- people with the same coordinates are in different groups
- people within a group should have different scores

I am not expecting a full-fledged algorithm but rather hints in the right direction. So far I am using a simple k-means algorithm which forms groups so that the distance between people gets minimized however the two other constraints are not considered, unfortunately.

Comment: What is the distance between two people in your case?

Comment: If there are 9 in a group but only 6 scores how do people within a group have different scores?

Comment: It may be a continuous score in [1,6]

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is actually called [**constrained clustering**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constrained_clustering#cite_ref-2)

There are different examples of them, but probably none as the one you want to do. For example, [this one by Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/tr-2000-65.pdf) imposes the constraint of neglect clusters with few points. Section 2 shows you how they imposed constrains.

An additional possible way is pure brute force: for each iteration of the algorithm, simply analyze the proposal given by k-means and reject it if it does not fulfill your requirements.

I recommend you to consider posting this question in [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) as well